# how to add additional parameters to a callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, parameter-passing, strophe

In my javascript XMPP project there is a core part and a plugin part. The core part must be independent of the plugin part. I am trying to call a core-function from the plugin part, that itself needs to call a plugin-function. since the core part by concept does not know of any plugin-functions, I am trying to hand the plugin-function over as a callback function. Here it goes:

There is the [strophe-library](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs) and the [muc-plugin](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/muc/strophe.muc.js) which holds the `join`-[function](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/muc/strophe.muc.js#L33).

I added a function `joinMuc` myself to the core, so that it can have a callback, which is not provided by the original function:

```
core = {
    joinMuc: function(room, onMessage, onPresence, onRoster, result) {
        MX.connection.muc.join(
            room,
            jQuery.jStorage.get('settings').username,
            onMessage,
            onPresence,
            onRoster
        );
        if (result) result(room);
    },
}
```

I call `core.joinMuc` and pass the parameters and callback functions:

```
plugin = {
    doHtml: function(result) {
        //…
    },
    doPlain: function(result) {
        //…
    },
    joinGame: function(chatroom){
        core.joinMuc(
            chatroom,
            core.onMessage,
            core.onPresence,
            core.onRoster,
            function(result){
                //…
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`core.onMessage` will get the actual xmpp-message as a parameter from the `join`-[function](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/muc/strophe.muc.js#L33), but now here is the tricky part: I actually need three parameters for `core.onMessage` to hand over the two plugin functions of which one is supposed to to be run after `core.onMessage` decided what kind of message it is:

```
core = {
    onMessage: function (message, handleHTMLMessage, handlePlainMessage){
        var rawMessageBody = $(message).find('body').text();
        var parsedMessageHtml = $.parseHTML(rawMessageBody)[0];
        if ( parsedMessageHtml.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'foo' ) {
            handleHTMLMessage(parsedMessageHtml);
        } else {
            handlePlainMessage(rawMessageBody);
        }
        return true;
    },
}
```

So now my question is: how can I call `core.onMessage` with two extra parameters? I tried to call `core.onMessage(plugin.doHtml,plugin.doPlain)` as parameter of `core.joinMuc` but that ended up in an infinite loop that crashed the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
// probably namespaced somewhere, but this is the idea
var createMessageHandler = function(handleHTMLMessage, handlePlainMessage) {
    return function(message) {
        core.onMessage(message, handleHTMLMessage, handlePlainMessage);
    };
};
```

Then:

```
plugin = {
    doHtml: function(result) { /* ... */},
    doPlain: function(result) { /* ... */},
    joinGame: function(chatroom){
        core.joinMuc(
            chatroom,
            createMessageHandler(plugin.doHtml, plugin.doPlain),
            //…
        );
    }
}
```

I don't particularly like the internal references to `plugin` from within `plugin` and would probably refactor to avoid them, but this might be an easy way to get going.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, this helps. I accepted this as answer, even though Vivins solution would work too, but since the project is rather scientific or educational, this one is more „verbose“ and therefore is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use an anonymous function that ends up calling `core.onMessage` with the required parameters:

```
core.joinMuc(
    chatroom,
    function(message) {            
        core.onMessage(message, plugin.doHtml, plugin.doPlain);
    },
    core.onPresence,
    core.onRoster,
    function(result){
        //...
    }
);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, thank you. see [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334827/how-to-add-additional-parameters-to-a-callback-function-in-javascript#comment30374788_20335471)

Comment: I didn't comment when this was first posted, because I wasn't really sure I understood the problem.  But assuming that I do understand correctly, and that the issue is that a third-party tool is calling the function supplied as a third parameter to `MX.connection.muc.join`, but calling it with only a single parameter, then I don't think this technique helps any.  This function will still be called with the same single parameter.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it will be called with whatever is passed in. This is essentially similar to what you have, except that I have defined the function inline. In your example it calls a function which returns a new function. In your case, `createMessageHandler` is invoked immediately, so it essentially behaves the same way. I did make a change to the parameters though.